# How to add windowed prompts and confirmations to php functions?

Tags: php

How do I add "Are you sure you want to" prompts and "the so and so action is done" confirmations for php functions.

I call my functions with:

```
<form action="functionname.php" method="post"><input type="submit"></form>
```

and i usualy resolve them with:

```
header("Location:" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

I know how to do prompts for javescript and jquery, but i need them to go when i click submit and i need conformations after REFERER page is reloaded? Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need JavaScript to do those dialogs. Your PHP can insert the correct code to raise the `alert` and `confirm` dialogs.

Comment: The **only** way you can accomplish this is with javascript `confirm` message boxes EDIT: and ninja'd!

Answer (score 0):

You are just fine with `Javascript` confirmations. It's good to have `window.confirm ("Are you sure?")` stuff to handle your needs.

While Javascript is easily hacked and manipulated, we will only realize that there's nothing the Server/ you would lose if one does that. The only result is that the client will no more show confirmation dialogs and stuff. That should make them (The hackers) feel like "Don't hack, don't lose"